# Unable to find path for video, in next js src Directory

Tags: next.js, directory, src, video-embedding

I tried to import the video through various methods, but it keeps giving errors, and I'm unable to embed the video.

here is the file of app/page.tsx

```
import {videoBg} from '../assets/video/videoBg.mp4'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <main className='min-h-screen'>
        <video
          muted
          loop
          autoPlay
          className="fixed -top-2 left-0 min-w-full min-h-full -z-50 object-cover"
        >
          <source src={videoBg} type="video/mp4" />
          <source src={videoBg} type="video/ogg" />
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
      </main>
      </>
  )
}
```

here is the directory structure

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtBK5.png)

Comment: I would start with the base directory of your project.  IE `import {videoBg} from 'assets/video/videoBg.mp4'`  If `assets` isn't at root level .. I'd `import {videoBg} from 'base/directory/assets/video/videoBg.mp4'`

Comment: you can check out the structure here https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtBK5.png can you guide me.

Comment: It appears `assets` is at base level ..  Make sure your `baseUrl` and `paths` are set accordingly in your `jsconfig.json` -- Then you should just be able to call it like: `import videoBg from 'assets/video/videoBg.mp4'`

Comment: Also include the error(s) you are receiving ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi if you want to solve your problem you should add folder video in public folder then add video file in video folder
after that you create env file for dev and product in env dev add http://localhost:{your port || 3000} then the complete path http://localhost:3000/videos/lions.mp4

env dev put NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL = http://localhost:3000 and
.env.production NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL = your domain server

```
 <video className="w-100" autoPlay  controls preload="none">
          <source
            src={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/videos/lions.mp4`}
            type="video/mp4"
          />
          <track
            src={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/videos/lions.mp4`}
            kind="subtitles"
            srclang="en"
            label="English"
          />
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
```